# How to fix "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'" error for MySQL using Mac OS X?

Tags: mysql, mac-os-x

After reading a few of the similar problems to mine and none of them working, I thought I'd attempt to be more specific to see if my root problem needed to be fixed differently than the others.

I've been using MySQL for about a year now and it's always worked fine -- but I got a new Macbook Pro (10.9.3) yesterday, and everything migrated and runs great except for MySQL. It's running:

[image: MySQLRunning]

My root user is enabled and I checked to see that the password is the same as my user login (and the same as it's always been) -- but every time I try to run it, whether it be through Terminal or through Sequel Pro, I always get the same:

`Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`

I also traditionally use Sequel Pro -- which migrated over from my old computer without any problems, and retained the connection details its always had:

[image: SequelPro]

But I'm getting the same error message through Sequel Pro as I am through Terminal:

[image: SequelProError]

Does anybody have any ideas of things I can try? After attempting some of the other similar questions on here, I've unfortunately come up with nothing.

Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

Run this **/usr/bin/mysql_upgrade -u root -p**
This should reset the rights and grant access with u logged in as **'root'@'localhost'**
Thereafter run this **/usr/bin/mysql -u root -p**... et viola!